# Combining two variables into new variable

Tags: r, if-statement

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

I have A and B and want to get AB as the max of A or B and account for NAs

```
A<-c(1,1,1,0,0,0,NA,NA,NA)
B<-c(1,0,NA,1,0,NA,1,0,NA)
AB<-c(1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,NA)
TEST<-cbind(A,B,AB)

      A  B AB
[1,]  1  1  1
[2,]  1  0  1
[3,]  1 NA  1
[4,]  0  1  1
[5,]  0  0  0
[6,]  0 NA  0
[7,] NA  1  1
[8,] NA  0  0
[9,] NA NA NA
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `pmax()` function with `na.rm=TRUE`:

```
> AB <- pmax(A, B, na.rm=TRUE)
> TEST <- cbind(A, B, AB)
> TEST
       A  B AB
 [1,]  1  1  1
 [2,]  1  0  1
 [3,]  1 NA  1
 [4,]  0  1  1
 [5,]  0  0  0
 [6,]  0 NA  0
 [7,] NA  1  1
 [8,] NA  0  0
 [9,] NA NA NA
```